# Use running instance of Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

On my pc I have a running instance of tomcat, that I use with axis to export web-services. I'd like to use the same instance of tomcat with eclipse to run my servlets. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

create a basic web project in eclipse and try to deploy it, then it should ask for the server. if your eclipse is already configured with tomcat (even on axis), it should display for you to select as the application server.

try this [tutorial](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2012/02/adding-tomcat-application-server-to.html) which shows how to make it work. 
it shows from the scratch (download tomcat and configure with Eclipse) but you can get an idea on the latter configuration.